# Changing the user language on Windows7

Tags: windows-7, username

My OS on my computer is Windows7. When I got this computer, I set my user name to a name in a non-latin language. Now I want to change it, because it causes many problems with some of the downloads. How can I change it so under the folder **C:/Users/????** My username will get a new (latin) name? I've tried to do it manulally, but it won't let me.

Comment: Are you the only user on the machine?

Answer (score 2):

Open `C:\Users` and create a new folder with the latin name, for example `limlim`. Then open a command prompt and type in `net user username /homedir:C:\Users\limlim`. You may need to run cmd.exe as an administrator to do this. Another thing you can do is go into library properties (e.g. Documents, Pictures, etc.) in Windows explorer, add the new directory, and set as default save location.

You may also be able to change your actual username, but you will have to create a new admin account (which can be deleted later), logout, login as the temporary admin, change your username, then logout and log back in as yourself.

If none of this works you may have to create a new user account (an administrator) with your new username and fix all of your settings. Then if you want you can delete the old user account (make sure to back up your files).